# Integration testing for image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, carrierwave

I learned how to test image file uploading from this excellent article:
https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/2014/using-test-fixtures-with-carrierwave/

Adapting those ideas for my app, I've got this test that works:

```
test "uploads an image" do
    pic = Picture.create(:image => fixture_file_upload('/files/DJ.jpg','image/jpg'), :user => User.first) 
    assert(File.exists?(pic.reload.image.file.path))
end
```

I would like to test the same thing for the user interface, so I would think that this test would also pass:

```
test "create new picture" do
    capybara_login(@teacher_1)
    click_on("Upload Pictures")
    fill_in "picture_name", with: "Apple"
    attach_file('picture[image]', Rails.root + 'app/assets/images/apple.png')
    check("check_#{@user_l.id}")
    check("check_#{@admin_l.id}")
    click_on ("Create Picture")

    @new_pic = Picture.last
    assert_equal "Apple", @new_pic.name
    assert @new_pic.labels.include?(@user_l)
    assert @new_pic.labels.include?(@admin_l)
    assert @teacher_1, @new_pic.user
    assert File.exists?(@new_pic.reload.image.file.path)
end
```

But it fails on the last line, asserting the existence of the file.

Below are the parts of my test_helper that I thought would be relevant. I can show the whole test_helper if someone thinks it necessary.

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
require 'capybara/rails'
Minitest::Reporters.use!

CarrierWave.root = 'test/fixtures/files'

class CarrierWave::Mount::Mounter
  def store!
    # Not storing uploads in the tests
  end
end

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  include ApplicationHelper

  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

  CarrierWave.root = Rails.root.join('test/fixtures/files')

  def after_teardown
    super
    CarrierWave.clean_cached_files!(0)
  end
end
```

Everything appears to be working as expected in development and production.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: It looks like you've disabled storing of the file, so I would guess the test is correct in thelling you the file isn't actually at `@new_pic.reload.image.file.path`

Comment: That makes sense. And I think that disabling storage is what I want. Otherwise future tests could give a false positive, right? But why does the command line version work, while the capybara version doesn't?